# Proving a Certain Smooth Map $S^n\rightarrow S^n$ is a Diffeommorphism

Tags: differential-topology

I am given a smooth map $f:S^n\rightarrow S^n$, for $n\geq 2$, whose differential is injective at each point.  I am asked to prove that it is a diffeomorphism.  Since the differential is injective between manifolds of the same dimension, it is also surjective.  This makes $f$ a submersion.  Submersions are open and $S^n$ is both compact and Hausdorff.  Thus the image of $f$ is both open and closed.  Since $S^n$ is connected, this makes $f$ surjective.  The problem I am having is proving that $f$ is injective.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have it.  There is only one covering map $S^n\rightarrow S^n$, up to isomorphism, for $n\geq 2$.  If I can show that $f$ is a covering map I will be done.  Since every value $y\in S^n$ is regular, the set $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite, say $\{x_1\ldots,x_k\}$.  By the Inverse Function Theorem and the fact that $S^n$ is Hausdorff, I can find pairwise disjoint neighborhoods $x_i\in U_i$ that map homeomorphically to some neighborhood $y\in V_i$.  Then $V_1\cap \cdots\cap V_k-f(S^n-(U_1\cup\cdots\cup U_k))$ is an evenly covered neighborhood of $y$.

Comment: You still need to show $f^{-1}(V_1\cap\dots\cap V_k)\subset U_1\cup\dots\cup U_k$. Also, there is not just one covering map; but every covering map is single-sheeted.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think I have fixed it.

Comment: It is harder than you think: there are local diffeomorphisms which are finite-to-one but not coverings. What you need to use is the that that f is proper. You can check for instance the path lifting property using properness. Or appeal to Ehresmann's theorem.

Comment: @studiosus I do not see why my neighborhood of $y$ is not evenly covered.

Comment: That's because you did not write a complete argument. As I said, the data you are using is not enough to conclude that your map is a covering.

Comment: @studiosus: You're making this too complicated. It follows immediately from compactness of the domain. The OP has fixed the argument. Now the preimage of the set in the range is contained in $U_1\cup\dots\cup U_k$, hence is evenly covered. (BTW, you could also write open set more simply as this as $W=S^n - f\big(S^n-(U_1\cup\dots\cup U_k)\big)$. This is a standard undergraduate exercise (cf. the Stack of Records Theorem in Guillemin and Pollack) to show that a local homeomorphism from a compact space onto a Hausdorff space is a covering map.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yes, indeed, this is very standard, but the argument written above is incomplete. (Tell me where OP used the compactness assumption.)

Comment: @studiosus: To say that the set $W$ in the range is open!!

Comment: Oh, I see, then it is all fine.